# PendingIntent is not working on Android O

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-8.0-oreo

I have download notification in my application. I've added "Cancel" button to `NotificationCompat.Builder` by calling `addAction()` method. But button not working on Android O device. When I press "Cancel" button nothing happens. But button working on Android < O.

[image: Example Screenshot]

My `Notification`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.network_download)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(null)
            .addExtras(idBundle)
            .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, context.getString(R.string.cancel), getCancelPendingIntent(context, id))
            .setProgress(100, 30, true);
```

My `PendingIntent` :

```
private PendingIntent getCancelPendingIntent(Context context, int id){
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, id, new Intent("CANCEL_DOWNLOAD").putExtra("id", id), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Also I have `NotificationReceiver` :

```
public static class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("CANCEL_DOWNLOAD".equals(action) && context != null){
            int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
            NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (mgr != null)
                mgr.cancel(id);
            FtpManager.getInstance(new AppExecutors(), CredentialsManager.getInstance().getCredentials(context))
                    .cancelDownloading();
        }
    }
}
```

In `Manifest` file I have :

```
<receiver
        android:name="eu.warble.pjapp.util.NotificationsManager$NotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="CANCEL_DOWNLOAD" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Never** use an implicit `Intent` when an explicit `Intent` will do. Android O helps enforce this by banning the receipt of implicit `Intent` broadcasts from manifest-registered receivers.

Step #1: Remove the `<intent-filter>` from your `<receiver>` (which also means that you could get rid of `android:exported="false"`, as that is now the default value)

Step #2: Replace `new Intent("CANCEL_DOWNLOAD").putExtra("id", id)` with `new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class).putExtra("id", id)`

Comment: CommonsWare, I tried your solution but still notification actions aren't working on Oreo devices (after upgrading notification handling to support notification channeling).

Comment: @AndoAiron: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain your symptoms in detail.

Comment: CommonsWare, Thanks for the suggestion. Asked separately as a new question and here is the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979848/android-notification-actions-with-notification-channeling"

Comment: How do you get an action if we change based on your suggestion? I mean if broadcaster has 2 actions, cancel and continue download, lets say? how can we make that happen without intentfilters?

Comment: @batmaci: I would use an extra, as I show in Step #2.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much CommonsWare. It works for me. This is my code

```
    var notifyIntent = Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
                notifyIntent.action = "ACTION_UPDATE_BADGE"//hardcode in manifest

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    // only for oreo and newer versions
                    notifyIntent = Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroidO::class.java)
                }
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, it, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

In manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".firebase.NotificationBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_UPDATE_BADGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".firebase.NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroidO">
            <!--Android O not working when having this code
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_UPDATE_BADGE" />
            </intent-filter>-->
        </receiver>
```

Create 2 classes:

```
open class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {...}
open class NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroidO : NotificationBroadcastReceiver() {/*do nothing*/}
```

Comment: I tested on android 8.0.0 and it works well, but it happens error on android 8.1.0 china device. I'm investigating solution for it.

Comment: I found the root cause for this error on android 8.1. I click on each notification, it still works well. But I click on "group notification", it not working, it only reopens the app.

Comment: I found the root cause. When user click on group notification, the app will be restarted and number of notifications in the group not reduce. It can be the feature default of android Oreo. When user click on any notification in the group, my code works well and number of notifications in group is reduced. Thanks!

Comment: how is this "do nothing" for oreo? are you just ignoring oreo action?

Comment: NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroidO extend NotificationBroadcastReceiver, so we only implement code in NotificationBroadcastReceiver, we don't need implement code in NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroidO

Comment: You don't have to create two receivers! Leave only one and for all versions just send explicit intent (instead of action you set class name) - `notifyIntent = Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroid::class.java)` and in manifest - `<receiver android:name=".firebase.NotificationBroadcastReceiverAndroid"/>`